# UITableViewCell variable height with multiple UILabels and IB

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, uialertview

Alright so I have a situation here that is making me go crazy. I am loading a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell. Now this cell has couple of UILabel's in it.

so the order is:

Label1
Label2
Label3
Label4

Now Label2 has a fixed height. Label1, Label3 and Label4 will need to change their height according to the size of string. I am using the recommended way to calculate the height for each label using: **- sizeWithFont:c constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap**

But the label's are overlapping each other. Not sure how to position these labels?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to see how you're constructing your UITableViewCell. 

Are all your individual tableViewCell's different heights?

There is a method on the UITableViewDelegate protocol that you need to use if you want your cells to work properly too `-(CGFloat)tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 1):

Position the first label, get its size, and then position each subsequent label by the previous label's frame.

For convenience, you might put this code into a separate method, calling it once to generate that cell's height for use in the `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, as well as have those labels set up for the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.